# uitableview default images showing different size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I have one UItableView with images,title and description

When i run the app i can see the images are showing as large size but if i click that row then images become small(original size ).

May i know why this happening?

[image]

code

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    offerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.offerImage.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    cell.offerImage.layer.cornerRadius=9.0;
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    if([offertitle count]>0){
        // Configure the cell...

        NSLog(@"%@",backupImage);

      [cell.offerImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[backupImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]]
       ;

       cell.offerTitle.text=[offertitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.offerDetails.text=[offerDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    }
    // cell.websiteImage.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In UitableViewCell, the default image frame will be change based on setting UIImage. I means if you set tableview height as 50, so by default the Default Cell UIImageView height 50. so based on height imageview width will be change for displaying the image without blur.

so you have to take all images are at same size, or You have to create custom UIImageView in place of cell default UIImageview.